# Problem with images and Chrome, Firefox, IE

Tags: html, image, firefox, google-chrome, joomla

I have a Joomla website and I observe a problem with some images.

In Chrome images look really good and sharp but in Firefox and IE the images are not that sharp and the colors are a bit strange.

Take a look at the photos below. The difference is more obvious on the Standings were the emblems of the teams are really small.

Any suggestions??

Image using Chrome
[image: Image From Chrome]

Image using Firefox
[image]

Website URL:

http://www.neasalamis.net

Comment: Did you try with firefox and chrome? Windows? I am using Linux!

Comment: windows, I tried chrome and firefox,  even the images above are the same for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're telling the browser to scale the image from 150 pixels to 60 pixels.
Most browsers aren't good at that.

You should create images that are exactly the right size using an image editor.
This will give you complete control over how the image is scaled (image editors do a much better job than Firefox), and make the files smaller too.

Comment: So there is no solution without changing anything?

Comment: How can you expect to solve a problem without changing anything?

Comment: I thought that this was a problem with some browsers. Are Google Chrome Developers smarter than IE and Firefox Developers? I cannot accept that.

Comment: Firefox chooses performance over appearance.  High-quality image resizing is slow.  It also serves as a warning to developers; serving incorrectly-sized images is a bad idea.

Comment: I know I'm very late, but the different way browsers handle borders and padding can change the final size of the image, thus the difference in the images.